# Painfully slow Feed Me import of User accounts

Tags: plugin-feedme, queue

I'm aware of [this thread on Feed Me slow performance](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33048/craft-cms-feed-me-slow-performance), but I'm raising it as a separate thread in case there is anything particular about my circumstance that is pertinent.

I'm running Craft 3.4.18 and trying to import a large number of **users** (about 1,500) into a specific user group using Feed Me:

1. I'm using `.csv` sources on the local file system above web root
2. I'm importing:

   - Username (as email address string)
   - Email
   - First name
   - Last name
   - Shared password
   - User group string
3. I'm batching imports in 500s but because things are so slow will now try smaller batches
4. I have read and attended to the [performance](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/troubleshooting.html#performance) aspects of the Feed Me troubleshooting docs
5. There is plenty of memory and execution time allocation to Craft and the instance is on a dedicated Linux server with 8Gb of RAM

Imports are working without error, but paaaaaainfully slowly -- we're talking hours -- to the point of the import *process* being effectively useless*.

I have looked into [Andrew Welch's #1 solution](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms#solution-1-async-queue-plugin) to running the queue as a background process, but have bumped into [installation issues](https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue/issues/32) with the **Async Queue** plugin.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

---

I'd be happy in principle to do **SQL inserts** directly into the `craft_users` and `craft_usergroups_users` tables but I infer that's not an option since each hash of the shared password is unique and there is a unique UID to generate for each row too.

---

**Update on #3 above:**

I'm currently running a batch of 100 instead of 500 and that makes no difference to speed whatsoever.

Next step is perhaps to try a JSON feed instead of CSV?

---

*'Effectively useless' in the sense that although I have time to run extended imports right now, if it's going to generally take this long it's a non-starter for time-pressured imports.

---

**Second update on #3 above:**

An import batch of 100 I started over 2 hours ago has crept along incrementally, with me periodically reviewing its status during that time and seeing barely any change, and then…

I have just revisited it and it suddenly went from 64% complete and unchanging to 100%. Now onto the next batch to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer in my case is to use a **JSON** data source.

Importing users as `.json` instead of `.csv` appears to be about 10 times faster:

- With `.csv` importing 480 users took 2.5 hours
- With `.json` importing 455 users took 15 minutes

My JSON looked like this:

```
{"user": [
    {
        "username":"jane.doe@example.com",
        "email":"jane.doe@example.com",
        "firstName":"Jane",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "password":"User pass phrase",
        "groupName":"User group name"
    },
    {
        "username":"joe.bloggs@example.com",
        "email":"joe.bloggs@example.com",
        "firstName":"Joe",
        "lastName":"Bloggs",
        "password":"User pass phrase",
        "groupName":"User group name"
    }
]}
```